# Springboot findBY not working when returning List

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an endpoint that saves a user's transactions such that I can calculate a user's commission at the end of the month. The persisting of the transactions is working fine however, returning a list of transactions is not working. Its returning an empty list always even if there is data. I have tried different solutions but same result, what could I be missing. I am using mysql database to save my data. This is my code :

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commission", uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "transactionsReference")
        }
)
public class commission implements Serializable{

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int transactionId;
    private String customerIdentification;
    private String transactionsReference;
    private double commission;
    private double transactionAmount;
    private String transactionType;
    private String commissionClass;
    private String commissionName;
    private String transactionDate;

    public commission() {
    }

    public commission(String customerID, String transactionsReference, double commission, double transactionAmount, String transactionType, String commissionClass, String commissionName, String transactionDate) {
        this.customerIdentification = customerID;
        this.transactionsReference = transactionsReference;
        this.commission = commission;
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.commissionClass = commissionClass;
        this.commissionName = commissionName;
        this.transactionDate = transactionDate;
    }

  // Getters and setters omitted for brevity  

}
```

Repository :

```
public interface CommissionRepository extends CrudRepository<commission, Integer> {    

 public List<commission> findByCustomerIdentification(String customerId);
    public List<commission> findByCommissionClass(String comclass);
    public commission findByTransactionsReference(String ref); 

}
```

Service :

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CommisionService {

    @Autowired
    private CommissionRepository commission_repository;

    public List<commission> getAllCommissions(String customerid) {
        List<commission> userCommissions = commission_repository.findByCustomerIdentification(customerid);
        if (userCommissions == null) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Empty", "Missing Data Exception");
        }
        return userCommissions;
    }

}
```

Controller Class :

```
@RestController
@Api(value = "TransactionsAPI", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class CommissionsController {

    @Autowired
    private CommisionService transactionsService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/myendpoint/endpoint/getAll/customer/commissions/byCustomerID")
    @ApiOperation("Get all customer commissions")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = TransactionResponse.class)})
    public List<commission> getAllCollectionPoints(@Valid @RequestBody String cusid) {
        return transactionsService.getAllCommissions(cusid);
    }
}
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "commission", uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "transactionsReference")
        }
)
public class commission implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int transactionId;
    private String customerId;
    private String transactionsReference;
    private String commissionClass;

    public commission() {
    }

    public commission(String customerId, String transactionsReference, String commissionClass) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.transactionsReference = transactionsReference;
        this.commissionClass = commissionClass;
    }

    public int getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(int transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getTransactionsReference() {
        return transactionsReference;
    }

    public void setTransactionsReference(String transactionsReference) {
        this.transactionsReference = transactionsReference;
    }

    public String getCommissionClass() {
        return commissionClass;
    }

    public void setCommissionClass(String commissionClass) {
        this.commissionClass = commissionClass;
    }


}
```

Comment: `findBy` methods returning a `List` is core spring-data functionality.  Try turning on sql logging (or analog if it's a nosql flavour) and debugging.  I've noticed your parameter names are different from the property names, not sure if that matters, but all the examples have them the same as property.

Comment: It might be mapping issue. Can you share complete commission entity with annotations and getter-setters. Also, if you use column mapping annotations on getter methods, you should move Id and GeneratedValue to getter of transactionId.

Comment: I have updated the question by adding the entity class , @Arif